# Mildew around window retrofit inserts

Tags: insulation, windows, mold, moisture

Some of the windows in our house have mildew around the replacement window inserts (~18 years old).  Mostly at the bottom.  The original frames were aluminum, the inserts of course are PVC.

The windows were installed with about a 1/2" gap all around and there was a tiny bit of spray insulation installed to "seal."  But the cavity itself is mostly empty.  Then plastic strips were attached to the window to cover the gap, with a little bit of paint caulk around plastic.

My first round of trying to address this was to add a bead of polyurethane caulk around the outside of the exterior window frame.  I don't think this helped much.

Stepping back and thinking about the problem further... I think the problem isn't moisture getting in from outside, but rather the gap is getting *cold* from outside, warm moist air from inside gets into the gap, and then condenses?

So I'm formulating a plan, but want to add other people's experience and knowledge:

- remove strips
- 10% bleach spray around the gap, let dry
- Maybe also spray in concrobium spray, let dry
- Brush mold resistant Kilz primer into the gap?
- fill gap with some kind of insulation

  - fiberglass pushed in with fingers? (Hard to keep it from getting too dense though)
  - spray insulation foam cut flush after curing?  (Hard to remove and inspect later...)
  - precut neoprene foam strips? (Hard to fill in tiniest gaps)
- replace plastic cover strips

I think the main question assuming the rest of my plan is ok, is what to fill the gap with?  I'm hesitant to use spray insulation in case the mildew comes back and I need to pull it all back out.

Comment: Photos are always helpful in a case like this especially of the outside bottom so we can see how it is sealed.

Comment: @EdBeal Tried a photo, doesn't do it justice.  They put a small amount of expanding foam to cover the cracks to the outside, but there is almost zero insulation in the interior gap/ cavity that is normally covered by the strips.  Looking at some Anderson DIY instructions I see now they should have filled that entire gap with foam.